# Selenium 2 error with firefox 11.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm new with selenium 2 and i try to run a simple (bellow) exemple but when i use firefoxe 11.0 I got a window information : [Application javascript] TypeError: Componenets;classes[cid] is undefined

and i'm obligated to click OK button to see my script execution

How can I fixe this ?

```
public class WhenSearchingForDrupalUsingGoogleTest {

  private String baseUrl;
  private WebDriver driver;
  private ScreenshotHelper screenshotHelper;

  @Before
  public void openBrowser() {
    baseUrl = System.getProperty("webdriver.base.url");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    screenshotHelper = new ScreenshotHelper();
  }

  @After
  public void saveScreenshotAndCloseBrowser() throws IOException {
    screenshotHelper.saveScreenshot("screenshot.png");
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void pageTitleAfterSearchShouldBeginWithDrupal() throws IOException {

    assertEquals("The page title should equal Google at the start of the test.", "Google", driver.getTitle());

    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchField.sendKeys("Drupal!");
    searchField.submit();

    assertTrue("The page title should start with the search string after the search.",
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
          public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("drupal!");
          }
          }));
  }

  private class ScreenshotHelper {

    public void saveScreenshot(String screenshotFileName) throws IOException {
      File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
      FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(screenshotFileName));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 11 was released on March 13th 2012

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases

Selenium 2.20 was released on February 27th 2012

- http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
- http://seleniumhq.org/download/

With this in mind you can't really expect Selenium 2.20 to Support FireFox 11

Currently supported platform list:

- http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one(or many) of your add-ons are causing the problem. Did you try the solution [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/729606#answer-3778)?